Can I take ASA certifications online?
I am wondering if for the basic ASA (American Sailing Association) certifications 101 102 103 and 104 I can study by myself and take the certification tests online. The official website is not very clear on this.

What is unclear about the ASA statement "Each certification requires participants to fully satisfy both knowledge and skills standards, which will be verified through a written exam and an on-the-water practical exam" ?

You are right. Thanks for bringing that up. You could have done this in a kinder way, though. I bet you can do it. :-)

Yes I am sorry – it was a bit of a gybe.

What's all this about ?

@MartinF Getting a sailing certificate. A "gybe" is a sailing maneuvre that you better demonstrate correctly in an exam, because what is called a "crash gybe" is a maneuvre that will certainly flunk you.

@pmf - And "going about" is also a sailing maneuvre. :-)
